# If $X_i$ is not iid from normal a distribution, whether $(n-1)S^2$ is still follow chi-square distribution with $df = n-1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X = (X_1,...,X_n)$ is a random vector from $N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $$ \Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1     & \rho   & \dots  & \rho \\
   \rho   & 1      & \dots  & \rho \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   \rho   & \rho   & \dots  & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
we can get that $S^2$ is independent with $\bar{X}$, since $\Sigma = \sigma^2[(1-\rho)I + \rho11^T]$. If we set
$$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1-1/n    & 1/n    & \dots   & 1/n \\
    -1/n   & 1-1/n  & \dots   & -1/n \\
   \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
   -1/n    & -1/n   & \dots   & 1-1/n
\end{bmatrix},
$$ then we can get that $AX \sim N(A\mu, A\Sigma A^T)$ and then we can verify $S^2$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent because of the independence between $\bar{X}$ and $X_i - \bar{X}$. However, do we know that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ still follows a $\chi^2$ distribution with $df = n-1$? Since from the covariance\variance matrix of $AX$ we know the $X_i - \bar{X}$ and $X_j - \bar{X}$ are not independent, where $i$ is not equal to $j$.

If yes, how can we prove it? If no, which distribution does it follow?

Comment: $(n-1)S^2$ still follows $\chi^2_{n-1}$ when suitably scaled: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3915321/321264. But I don't see the point of using this  $A$.

Comment: But how can we scale it? Since if $X_i$ is independent, then $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}$ follows chi-square distribution with df=n-1, but now it seems like the denominator is not $\sigma^2$ and rather other scale factor?

Comment: @StubbornAtom : This matrix $A$ is used for defining $S^2,$ thus:
$$
AX = A\left[ \begin{array}{c} X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_n \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} X_1-\overline X \\ \vdots \\ X_n-\overline X \end{array}\right] \quad \text{ where } \overline X = \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n} n,
$$
and then
$$
(n-1)S^2 = \|AX\|^2.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $A$ is a symmetric idempotent matrix, i.e. $A = A^T = A^2.$ And $A1= 0$ if $1$ denotes the column vector whose every entry is the scalar $1.$

You have $\Sigma = (1-\rho)I + \rho 1 1^T$ but also $\Sigma = \sigma^2[(1-\rho)I + \rho 1 1^T].$ I will assume the latter was intended.

Then you have
$$
\operatorname{var}(AX) = \sigma^2 A[(1-\rho)I + \rho 11^T] A^T = \sigma^2 (1 - \rho ) A.
$$
Recall next that $(n-1)S^2 = \|AX\|^2.$

And recall that a suitable rotation of $\mathbb R^n$ transforms $X$ to a vector whose expected value is $(\mu\sqrt n,0,0,\ldots,0)^T$ and transforms $\sigma^2(1-\rho)A$ to
$$
\sigma^2(1-\rho)\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 \\ & 1 \\ & & 1 \\ & & & \ddots \\ & & & & 1 \end{array} \right].
$$
Hence we have
$$
\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2(1-\rho)} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I still have a question about why $(n-1)S^2 = ||AX||^2$?