# Show that for independent random variables $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$, the given random variables are independent.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, independence

Show that for independent random variables $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$, the random variables
$$
\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}, \quad S^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}
$$
are independent.

**Idea**:
I have found the following similar lemma, but it has a rather complicated proof. Unfortunately, so far I have not come across an easier way to show the above statement. Can someone help me further?

Lemma 7.4.9. If $ X \sim N\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right), X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n} $ are independent identically distributed random variables, $ X_{i} \stackrel{d}{=} X $, then $ \bar{X}_{n} $ and $ S_{n}^{2} $ are independent.

Comment: Isn't the standard proof to use Basu's theorem on complete and ancillary statistics? Also, I'm pretty sure the claim is true if and only if your data is gaussian.

Comment: @AndrewZhang See e.g. [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjXwqis6Y6AAxVsjIkEHXFmDjYQFnoECA0QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1809.03774&usg=AOvVaw2UrMET67CcXi_bkKt2SUlM&opi=89978449)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Proposition 1 is in your linked document is exactly what AndrewZhang is saying...

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted the link.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for providing the appropriate theorem with proof or derivation here. Now I am actually even more puzzled by the task, since one had to show exactly, as I wrote it above, in an exam with only 90 minutes...

Comment: @clementine1001 Basu's theorem is not needed and it is arguably not a standard proof of this result. A standard proof is a change of variables: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2952346/321264.